# Transfer Learning: Training from my pre-trained model produces model with large size

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, transfer-learning

Let's say I have two layer convolutional model like

```
Input -> conv -> conv -> flatten -> softmax 10 classes (cross entropy cost function)
```

I have saved this model using

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables()) 
....
# run session
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=training_step)
```

After saving the model-data-file size is of around 13 MB.

Next, I want to use this model to perform transfer learning. I have removed the last softmax layer(10 units) in the previous model and added a new conv and new softmax layer(6 units) in the new model architecture.

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# load model trained in previous step
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir))

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
output_after_conv = graph.get_tensor_by_name("flatten:0")
# freezed
flatten = tf.stop_gradient(output_after_conv )

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())

input = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")

# constructed input to be feeded
# added a conv layer to the graph
# added softmax layer to the graph
# defined cost function
# defined optimizer

# ran the session then saved the model
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=training_step)
```

This time the model-data-file size grew to 300 MB. I wonder what has caused this model size growth?.